# How to perfectly match a proxy with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I need to match both formats like: `user:pass@112.213.123.12:3847` and `111.23.123.78:2938`, how do you do that(**match valid proxy only**)?

And by the way, is there such module(validate proxy formats) in python already?

Comment: They are both URLs, without the scheme portion. I'd look at the [`urlparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) for validation.

Comment: As for matching those formats with regular expressions, you should be able to just simplify an existing URL-matching expression; no path portion needed, and no scheme.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there exists a package for validation already in Python.

However, you can use this regex that matches the right format, but will not validate if the IP is a valid IP4 address:

```
^(?:(\w+)(?::(\w+))?@)?((?:\d{1,3})(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?::(\d{1,5}))?$
```

It will also capture user, password, ip, and port individually

**positives:**

```
user:pass@112.213.123.12:3847
user@112.213.123.12:3847
10.10.0.1:1024
111.23.123.78:2938
10.124.0.1
0.0.0.0
```

**regex won't recognize if IP4 addresses are valid:**

```
10.20.456.123
```

**negatives:**

```
10.100.1
:user@10.124.10.1
user:@10.100.1.0:100
```

the regex is tested http://www.rubular.com/r/jErO9xqDS2

Comment: Well, it's not a simple 3 digit number, and the upper limit is 255. How to make it recognize this?

Comment: As I said it is not validated. You definitly don't want to do all in one regex, to keep it maintainable. You could validate in a second pass that it matches IP4 standards. split the ip address at \. and validate that each value is between 0 and 255. You also need to make sure that the port is in te range of 1 to 65535 with the same technique.

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With validation:

```
import re

samples = [
    'user:pass@123.123.123.123:1234',
    '123.123.123.123:1234',
    '123.123.123:123',
    '321.123.123.123',
    '123.123.123.123:123123']

def isValidUser(name):
    return re.match('\w+', name) != None

def isValidPass(passwd):
    return isValidUser(passwd)

def isValidIp(ip):
    if ip.count('.') != 3:
        return False
    else:
        valid = True
        for i in ip.split('.'):
            try:
                if 0 <= int(i) <= 255:
                    pass
                else:
                    valid = False
            except ValueError:
                return False
        return valid

def isValidPort(port):
    valid = False
    try:
        if 0 < int(port) < 2**16:
            valid = True
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return valid

def isValidProxy(proxy):
    m = re.match('^((([^:]+):([^@]+))@)?((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:(\d{1,5}))?$', proxy)
    if m is None:
        return False
    user = m.group(3) or 'user'
    passwd = m.group(4) or 'pass'
    ip = m.group(5)
    port = m.group(8) or '1234'

    return isValidUser(user) and isValidPass(passwd) and isValidIp(ip) and isValidPort(port)

for n in samples:
    print isValidProxy(n)
```

I assumed port is optional. If you require port change:

```
    port = m.group(8) or '1234'
```

to

```
    port = m.group(8)
```

and/or change:

```
    m = re.match('^((([^:]+):([^@]+))@)?((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:(\d{1,5}))?$', proxy)
```

to

```
    m = re.match('^((([^:]+):([^@]+))@)?((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(:(\d{1,5}))$', proxy)
```

Comment: The code would consider 999.999.999.999:999 as a valid IP address while the upper limit should be 255...

Comment: Reuse existing code, then you cope with host names instead of IP addresses and variations in IP address formats as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**
Use [google-url (GURL)](https://code.google.com/p/google-url/) C++ library to parse and validate url. [There](https://code.google.com/p/python-google-url/) is Python wrapper.

Comment: Can you please mention your reason for preferring urlparse?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm currently using to accept http / https only, username:password optionally and host as an IP or domain name is the following:

> `^(?:https?:\/\/)(?:(\w+)(?::(\w*))@)?([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1}\.([a-zA-Z]{1,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})|((?:\d{1,3})(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}))(?::(\d{1,5}))$`

I hope it helps